# Indenting within block comments in C-mode Emacs

Tags: indentation, comment, cc-mode

After writing functions in C/C++, I like to format my block comments that explain a function's purpose, parameters, use, and so on.

(See example below)
[image: Desired Emacs Comment Style]

However, to indent my comments in emacs, I need to do `C-q TAB`, which is a bit of an awkward set of keystrokes (not to mention having to press three keys as opposed to one).

My question is: what would the Elisp code be for:

1. See whether or not what I'm typing is in a comment block (I'm thinking it has to do with `font-lock-comment-face` but I'm not sure
2. If the text is inside a block comment, have `TAB` perform the same functionality as the aforementioned `C-q TAB`

For more information, some of the shortcuts given in the Emacs guide, such as `M-j` are helpful, but I still need to `C-q TAB` to initially indent a region within the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to check if you are in a comment is to use [`syntax-ppss`](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/14270/237).

A simple way to do what you want would be something like:

```
(defun my/c-indent-or-tab-in-comment ()
  (interactive)
  (if (nth 4 (syntax-ppss))
      (insert "\t")
    (call-interactively 'indent-for-tab-command)))

(define-key c-mode-map (kbd "TAB") #'my/c-indent-or-tab-in-comment)
```

Some other possible approaches: modify the `indent-line-function` variable to point to a function that does what you want, or define [advice](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12997/how-do-i-use-nadvice) on `indent-for-tab-command`.

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped immensely. For future reference, I used the `(kbd "<tab>")` command on my terminal. I am relatively new to elisp and all the crazy customizations it provides, so I was wondering what prefixing the argument and padding it to `indent-for-tab-command` would be used for. Again, many thanks!